# How do I find the mapping that is overriding Control-W =?

Tags: key-bindings

I am currently running a few plugins (git gutter, fugitive), and it appears that one of them has overridden the behavior of `Control-W,=` so that instead of making vertically split windows have equal height, it maximizes the height of the top one.

I would like to restore the original behavior, so I tried to look for the mapping in the output of `:map` and `:nmap`, but I did not see it.

Is there a different place to look for figuring out how to undo this mapping (or some option that is changing this behavior)?

Comment: Are you sure you’re not pressing `<C-w>_`, which might be similar to your equal key? That would maximize height I believe.

Comment: Yup, I'm sure. Because `vim -u None` does not exhibit the bad behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just did a binary search on my vimrc and plugins and discovered the following line in my vimrc that caused this strange behavior:

```
set laststatus=3
```

When I commented this out, the silly behavior went away.

Comment: Indeed. And behavior is really odd under that setting. Documentation suggests it should only be set to 0, 1 or 2, so wondering why it behaves so oddly under value 3... (Perhaps a mix of behavior of 1 and 2?) Looks like a bug to me, consider reporting it upstream.